# Programmatically retrieve infiniband device ip address

Tags: c, linux, rdma, infiniband

I'm trying to find programmatically the inet address of an Infiniband interface whose name is not know *a priori*.

I'm on Linux, and I would like to avoid the parsing of `ifconfig (8)` output. 
I've read the second comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2989481/148481) answer, that suggests to use `getifaddrs()` to retrieve the interfaces, but then I cannot select the Infiniband one.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getifaddrs()` returns one entry of type `AF_PACKET` for each interface, which has hardware address details, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762766/mac-address-with-getifaddrs).  In particular, the `iface->ifa_addr` holds a `struct sockaddr_ll`, and the `sll_hatype` member of that structure holds the hardware address type.  So to figure out which interfaces are IPoIB you can just check which ones have hardware type `ARPHRD_INFINIBAND`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I recovered the ib interface name and then iterated again on the list (returned by `getifaddrs`) to get the entry with the type `AF_INET`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try parsing some file under `/proc/net/` like `/proc/net/if_inet6` & `/proc/net/dev`. You can learn what `ifconfig` does by `strace`-ing it.