# Find available network interfaces in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking, ubuntu

Does anyone know a C/C++ code for finding the network interfaces available?

I've been looking for some code, but most times they are quite complex. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: look at the ifconfig source for linux? Or, the opensource versions of ethereal?

Comment: Unbutu/Linux. I'm new on this, and I've been looking for some codes, on the internet, but some of then are bit hard to understand.

Comment: to give you an idea of the system calls needed, run `netstat` under `strace` as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2989470/283302).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See the [getifaddrs](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) man page.  There is an example program towards the end.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for this in context of a desktop application, and you want to be notified of changes (e.g. interfaces connecting/disconnecting), consider using DBus to monitor NetworkManager.

http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/api/09/spec.html

You can enumerate interfaces, as well as interface-specific things (like available and connected WiFi access points, configured-but-not-dialed PPP links, and so forth), and if anything changes, you'll receive a notification over the DBus.

(If this is for something more like a server program, where you expect the network configuration to remain more stable, then things like `getifaddrs` are possibly more appropriate.)