# How to get all network interface name and information in c++

Tags: c++, linux, networking, interface

Is it possible to get all network interfaces(whether **up** or **down**) name and available information in Linux using c++? I mean a program that only uses **API** to get interface's name.
Does "ioctl" print **down** interfaces?

Comment: [This is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434918/find-available-network-interfaces-in-c-c), search first.

Comment: @xingouy. I saw that before. I want to get all interfaces not only availables!

Comment: @x5lcfd I did search, this was the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not specially for C++, but you can use the C API and the 'getifaddrs' function to do so: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html

Comment: Can you explain the example of 'getifaddrs' in the page? why "for" statement runs 6 times while I have only 2 interfaces lo and eth0?

Comment: From the notes section, "The addresses returned on Linux will usually be the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses assigned to the interface, but also one AF_PACKET address per interface containing lower-level details about the interface and its physical layer." So you get the addresses for ipv4, ipv6, and ethernet address in different ifaddr structs.