# List of network interface names, using C with Winsock?

Tags: c, winsock2, windows-networking

In Windows' C API, how can you get a list of network interface names?  (Equivalent to [`getifaddrs()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434918/find-available-network-interfaces-in-c-c) in Linux)

The `WSAIoctl(sock, SIO_GET_INTERFACE_LIST_EX, ...)` function seems to only return IP addresses, plus a little metadata.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does this.

Use [`GetIpAddrTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you are interested in IPv4 addresses only.