# sysfs, ifreq, IOCTL or ??? to programatically monitor network status

Tags: c, linux, networking, sysfs

We have an embedded SoC running BusyBox Linux (kernel 2.6.x), and we have a need to monitor or at least notice in a timely manner when the network connection goes down or comes up (catching other events would be good but not essential).

I've spent a long time googling & reading SO threads and there seems to be a ton of different answers depending on the exact task at hand on the particular OS and the phases of the moon etc.

Our specific criteria are:

- We are looking from inside a C program, so C code is preferable to command line calls.
- Although the interface is always there, we can't guarantee it is or has ever been up (I have seen comments on some examples that only work when the interface is `up` even if the link is `down`)
- It would be nice not to have to poll, but rather to send/catch status change messages as and when they happen. I believe the kernel may already get such messages from the driver, but I'm not sure if there's anything we can hook into?

I've narrowed the likely seeming answers down to a few candidates but can't work out which is the nicest (least overhead, most reliable, least likely to break in future versions):

- `cat sys/class/net/eth0/operstate`
- `cat sys/class/net/eth0/carrier` **(I can find no good explanation of the difference between these two)**
- Using ifreq or various sequences of ioctl calls to read the socket status (looks kinda messy to me) as per [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989481/1389218) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15905276/1389218) (more tidy looking).
- Somehow catch status change messages???

Answer (score -1):

You can use inotify to keep check on the /sys/class/net/eth0/operstate. Inotify allows different events to be watched on specified file or directory e.g. CREATE, MODIFY, WRITE etc.

You can seen the working example [here](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/inotify/demo_inotify.c.html)