# Get multiple network interface gateway address in linux

Tags: c, linux, networking, interface, gateway

There are many ways to get the network interfaces IP adresses in GNU/Linux (for example with ioctl calls). And also, default gateway from the routing table is available in C.

But I have 2 network interfaces in 2 different networks. Each of these have unique router IP addresses (gateway addresses). How can I get these addresses? The DHCP offers tells them as well and I'm able to get them with `nmcli device list` for example. But where is this information stored? The NetworkManager database? I want to reach them from C.

Comment: read `/proc/net/if_inet6`

Comment: According to this page: [link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/proc-net.html) 
Thats not exactly what I need, but thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux an IPv4 interface's gateway can be read from `/proc/net/route`.